# Insert an array of Ruby objects in a Mongo database

Tags: ruby, mongodb-ruby

So, I'm using the Ruby MongoDB driver and I want to insert and object like this:

```
 db.insert_one({
  'game_id' => @token,
  'board' => {
    'tiles' => @board.tiles
  }
})
```

where @board is an instance of a Board class.

```
class Board
 attr_accessor :tiles
  def initialize()
    @tiles = [Tile.new, Tile.new]
  end
end
```

and Tile

```
class Tile
  def initialize()
    @x = 1, @y = 1
  end
  def to_json(options)
    {"x" => @x, "y" => @y}.to_json
  end
end
```

So at the end, 'tiles' field should look like this:

```
'tiles': [{x:1, y:1}, {x:1, y:1}]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `bson_type' for #<Tile:0x007ff7148d2440>
```

The gems I'm using: 'sinatra', 'mongo (2.0.4)' and 'bson_ext' (all required using Bundler.require). Thanks!

Comment: The error is telling you that the driver doesn't know how to put a `Tile` instance into MongoDB, MongoDB doesn't know what to do with `Tile`s and no one will automatically call `to_json` for you.

Comment: I've tried calling to_json, but it inserts the content as a String (a json string), not as an Array.

Comment: `to_json` returns a string, `as_json` returns a Hash. Yes, the naming is a bit confusing. Sorry, that wasn't my clearest comment ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply transform @board.tiles from collection of `Objects` to collection of ruby `Hashes`:

```
class Tile
  def initialize()
    @x = 1, @y = 1
  end
  def raw_data
    {"x" => @x, "y" => @y}
  end
end

db.insert_one({
  'game_id' => @token,
  'board' => {
    'tiles' => @board.tiles.map(&:raw_data)
  }
})
```

For more complex thing I recommend you to use mongoid http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/

Comment: (I cannot prove the code right now) But that would insert a (json )string and not an array, right? I'm aware of Mongoid, I just thought my problem was easy enough to use the native driver :p Thanks!

Comment: @enrmarc You are almost right. There was a problem in my solution. It was transforming `tiles` to array of strings. But now I modified it to return an array of hashes